# How to put a series of terminal commands in a shortcut icon on the taskbar in kde?

Tags: terminal, kde, desktop-shortcuts

Is there a way to make a icon shortcut on the taskbar to open emacs by running

```
SNAP=1 SNAP_NAME=1 SNAP_REVISION=1 /home/felipe/emacs/src/emacs
```

in the terminal when I click on it?

I asked this on the emas stack exchange wrongly, and was redirected to [specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest) and to use a `.desktop` file to do this, but this doesn't really answer my question, how do I do this?

And is there a way to make it so that when I run emacs by this method the terminal doesn't keep open as a window on the background?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Configurable Button](https://store.kde.org/p/1297839) widget.